# Existence of Integrating Factor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Someone has claimed that, if $$f_1(x, y)dx + f_2 (x, y) dy = 0$$ is not exact, then there is always some integrating factor $g$ such that $$g(x, y) f_1 (x, y) dx + g(x, y) f_2 (x, y) dy = 0$$ is exact.

Where can I find a proof of this?

Though I realize we may not be able to obtain $g$ explicitly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this statement is true in every case, but if you assume that the DE has a general solution, have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101694/529121.

Comment: I think this is true if there are no $x, y$ such that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are zero at $(x, y)$. If there are, then it's more complicated. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710242/conditions-on-a-1-form-in-mathbbr3-for-there-to-exist-a-function-such-th